# Download large files from s3 via php

Tags: php, amazon-s3, download, large-files

I have managed to upload large files to s3 using multiPart Upload, but I can't download them again using the getObject function. Is there another way I can achieve this?

Here my code:

```
  $keyname= 'key';
  $bucket = 'bucketname';
  $fileName = 'filename.txt';

  $result = $s3->getObject([
      'Bucket' => $bucket,
      'Key'    => $keyname
  ]);

  var_dump($fileName);
  $result['ContentDisposition'] = 'attachment; filename="'.$fileName.'"';

  $result['fileName'] = $result['ContentDisposition'];
  header("Content-Type: {$result['ContentType']}");
  header("Content-Disposition: {$result['ContentDisposition']}");
  header("Content-Length: {$result['ContentLength']}");
  echo $result['Body'];
```

**Thanks For the help. This is my solution:**

```
  $keyname= 'key';
  $bucket = 'bucketname';
  $fileName = 'filename.txt';

  #create S3 Client
  $s3 = new S3Client([
      'version' => 'latest',
      'region'  => 'eu-central-1',
      'credentials' => [
      ]
  ]);

      $cmd = $s3->getCommand('GetObject', [
          'Bucket' => $bucket,
          'Key' => $keyname,
          'ResponseContentDisposition' => 'attachment; filename="'.$fileName.'"'
      ]);

      $request = $s3->createPresignedRequest($cmd, '+15 min');
      $presignedUrl = (string)$request->getUri();

      echo $presignedUrl;
```

after this, I download it in my frontend with an a tag via js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can create a Presigned connection with S3 like this

```
$keyname= 'key';
$bucket = 'bucketname';
$fileName = 'filename.txt';

$command = $s3->getCommand('GetObject', array(
       'Bucket' => $bucket,
       'Key'    => $keyname  
       'ResponseContentDisposition' => 'attachment; filename="'.$fileName.'"'
));

$signedUrl = $command->createPresignedUrl('+15 minutes');
header('Location: '.$signedUrl);
```

Comment: If i try this, my code do nothing...if I comment the getCommand the code works.
Is there evtl. a Problem because the php code run on an ec2?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/feature-commands.html  $s3 is aws s3 client

Comment: ok after a little bit more testing i see it is a problem with the createPresignedUrl. It's not working in my code. Any Idea?

Comment: createPresignedUrl is a private method. You should use the method createPresignedRequest, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/s3-presigned-url.html